# SQL serverのnumeric型に小数を登録すると0になる

Tags: c#, sql-server

c#のプログラムでdouble型変数を用いて演算を行い、SQL serverのnumeric(12,3)の型のカラムに登録したら0になってしまいました。

実際の演算式は下記で999999999.999-999999999.998
答えは0.001となっています。

この答えをオラクルnumber(12,3)に登録すると0.001になりましたがSQL serverに登録したら0になってしまったのです。

登録時のパラメーターのマッピング方法がが間違っているのでしょうか。

Comment: とりあえずSQL Serverにnumber型は存在しません。numericでしょうか？ 重要な点であり単なる間違いとは思えないのですが…

Comment: すみません。間違えました。修正いたします。

Comment: どのような方法でC#からDBを操作しているのでしょうか？ 前提部分がわからないので「登録時のパラメーターのマッピング方法」の正否も判断できません。

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Serverのnumeric型](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)は精度を指定しなかった場合、`numeric(18,0)`となります。scale=0ですので整数しか扱えません。たぶんこれが原因です。

質問文にはC#からSQL Serverにどのような方法でデータを渡したのかが言及されていませんが、渡す際に精度が指定されていなかったのだろうと推測します。例えばC#の`decimal`（.NETの`System.Decimal`）を精度ヒント無しで自動変換した、とか。

Answer (score 0):

double型での計算結果が0.001未満になっていたことが原因のようです。
オラクルではその結果を0.001で登録してくれますが、SQL serverでは、0.000で切り捨てて登録されました。

演算の際、一度decimal型で計算し、その結果を登録することで解決できました。